# rsub connect_to localhost: unknown host (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sublimetext3, sublimetext

(Tag recommendations for adding or removing are welcome)

I've installed Sublime 3 and followed the instructions to set up rsub to work with files on a remote host. Specifically I have:

1. Installed rsub with Sublime 3 using package manager
2. On my remote server:

   wget -O /usr/local/bin/rsub \https://raw.github.com/aurora/rmate/master/rmate
    chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/rsub
3. Restarted my remote server `sudo shutdown -r now`
4. In my ~/.ssh/config I set what I have below this list
5. Then I ssh in: `ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 aws`
6. Then I tried to open a file: `rsub path/to/myfile.py`
   Resulted in:

> connect_to localhost: unknown host (nodename nor servname provided, or
>   not known)

My ssh config:

```
Host aws
Hostname ec2-12-345-6-789.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
User ubuntu
ForwardAgent yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key.pem
RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698
```

I also tried ssh ing with just:

```
ssh aws
```

This time I get this error message:

> connect_to 127.0.0.1 port 52698: failed.

How can I use rsub to work on remote scripts with Sublime? Why am I hitting these error messages and how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same error message as well. I found that I simply had to have the sublime text application open before executing the rsub command on the command-line.